# calling C# function immediately file is selected in fileupload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a web form(asp.net) which I'm using to upload file. In current situation if a user choose a text file from their computer they have to click a buttton to upload the text in a box. I'm trying to find a way to skip the step with a button pressing.

How to call a C# function when the file is selected from user ?

Comment: You need to use Javascript.

Comment: your question is not clear, you trying to find a way to do skip what?

Comment: can u elaborate i am not familiar with javascript

Comment: @Arbaaz i am trying to make user skip clicking button after selecting file, for loading text in textbox (from the file)

Comment: elaborate more, are you using ajax? if you want to just start file uploading when you select a file then you should try using some Jquery on UI and HttpHandler on Server side.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this

```
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload01" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="this.form.submit()"   runat="server"/>
```

in code behind Page_load event

```
if (IsPostBack && FileUpload01.PostedFile != null)
{
   if (FileUpload01.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
   {    
       FileUpload01.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + FileUpload01.PostedFile.FileName);   
       imguser.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + FileUpload01.PostedFile.FileName;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is great and exactly what I was looking for.  I do have one issue though.  When it posts back the FileUpload textbox is empty.  I put a breakpoint in the nested if statement and found that the posted file details are still there but the text in the textbox is gone.  So as far as the user is concerned, nothing was selected.

Comment: @Jeremy, was this ever resolved? I'm trying to do the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: This answer solves the problem. Just for simplify code, instead of using FileUpload01.PostedFile != null and FileUpload01.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0, you can use FileUpload01.HasFile.